# Disable specific endpoint from protectedResources on MSAL Angular

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

im working with MSALv2 on Angular 8, and I need disable the authentication for specific endpoints that dont need, is this possible?
Here is my config:

```
export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
  protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']);
  protectedResourceMap.set(`${environment.API_URL}`, ['api://f70731a6-6df1-4762-b267-54ea9741a7a2/User.read']);
```

And I need disable the auth only for
${environment.API_URL}` / x-resource
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in protected resource map, set the scope to null for that particular endpoint, and make sure that it is placed before any other wildcard endpoints which may match.

For example, if `${environment.API_URL}`is all protected, except for the endpoint `${environment.API_URL}/signup` then your protectedResourceMap would look something like:

```
const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string> | null>();
protectedResourceMap.set(`${environment.API_URL}/signup`, null);
protectedResourceMap.set(`${environment.API_URL`, environment.API_SCOPES);
```

Comment: This is the answer. See also the [Protected Resource Map](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/msal-interceptor.md#protected-resource-map) doco on github.

Comment: It seems to work for me! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

To have specific routes be accessible without authentication in your angular side you should use this route:

`{ path: '/home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}`

To protect your endpoint you should add canActive attribute in your route.

```
{ path: '/home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActive: [authService]}}
```

By doing this you can access specific route without authentication.

Comment: question is about excluding an endpoint at MSAL level, not Angular route